How do I switch from Ubuntu to windows in a dual boot, windows will pop up for a split second while starting up
The prompt to change between will show up for a split second and then go into Ubuntu instead of letting me pick or wait the ten seconds. I have tried esc and f10, f12, f2 etc…

Depending on your install (MBR or GPT) you assert SHIFT or ESC (hit key repeatadly during boot) to activate the grub menu which may or may not contain the Windows option.
As a starting point, boot into UBUNTU and do the following: -
Using your favourate editor (I use vi) edit the following: -
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

Change GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true To GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
Which should be enough to get the grub menu to appear
You can additionally change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden To GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
and change GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 To GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
Then run the following: -
sudo update-grub

This updates this file /boot/grub/grub.cfg using scripts in /etc/grub.d/
Then just reboot.

If you have recent hardware (GPT/UEFI) you should also be able to show the UEFI (BIOS) menu which should give you another way in. Making this happen will depend on the particular hardware and BIOS (you didn't say) so you should try and find a user manual for your particular case.
